# Does cooking a meat that's about to expire lengthen how long it's "good" for?

Tags: food-safety, meat

So like, if have a meat that has a particular "use by" date, and I cook it - I will kill a lot of the bacteria. Then if I refrigerate reasonably fast, will it last longer than it would've if I just left it alone? Are the two times I passed it through the Danger Zone negligible in comparison to how much bacteria I've killed?

Comment: It should stop the processes that would cause the meat to putrify.

What it will not do is break down all of the toxins that may have been created, and so if the colonies havea chance to rebuild, you can still get sick from it.